# Can rematch immer plugin control auto freeze switch just like immer using setAutoFreeze(true/false)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Using immer, i can control whether to freeze object returned by produce function by using setAutoFreeze function. How can I do this if using immer plugin?

Answer (score 2):

from what I can see, this should work fine. Shouldn't be hard to test though.

```
import immerPlugin from "@rematch/immer";
import { init } from "@rematch/core";
import { setAutoFreeze } from "immer";
setAutoFreeze(true);
```

The immer module index.js instantiates an instance of the immer class

```
const immer = new Immer()
export const produce = immer.produce
export default produce
```

and exports a bound copy of `setAutoFreeze`

```
export const setAutoFreeze = immer.setAutoFreeze.bind(immer)
```

https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/blob/master/src/index.js

so when you import `setAutoFreeze` it should be bound to the same (one and only) instance of `immer` that the rematch plugin is using.